# Unwanted i18n in Spring Security's error message

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a problem with Spring Security 3 and probably with i18n. I use Velocity for my view templates and I have the following code in one of them:

```
#if($SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION)
    <div class="error"><p>#springMessage($SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message)</p></div>
#end
```

When user tried to login and he passed bad credentials for example, there should be error message shown on the page. The problem is that application try to resolve message in locale 'pl' and I receive the following exception:

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'Bad credentials' for locale 'pl'.
```

In my configuration files I don't have any informations about i18n because I just don't need it.
I noticed that information about 'pl' locale can be retrieved from request (header `Accept-Language: pl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3`).

How to ignore this and serve pages only in defult language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want i18n, don't use `#springMessage`. `$SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message` is a message itself, not message code, thus you need to output it as is (though I'm not sure about HTML escape in Velocity):

```
#if($SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION)
    <div class="error"><p>${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}</p></div>
#end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had fun with il8n in the past. What I do is to force spring to only use the default language, I've done this by using a FixedLocaleResolver in the config files. Change the value to which ever locale you want to have as default.

```
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.FixedLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en_US" />
</bean>
```

Comment: The problem is solved by axtavt. My customized messages for authentication errors are in my messages.properties file. It's configured in this way:
`<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" p:basename="messages" />`.